# How to save an Aspose.PDF Document between disposing memory streams?

Tags: c#, memorystream, aspose.pdf

I'm loading byte arrays into objects and then concatenating these together. The problem is that whenever my using statement is exiting, the stream is closed and my concatenated object fails because some its resources have been disposed. I have been trying to save the result in between to a new stream but this also fails. This is my code:

```
public byte[] Merge(IEnumerable<byte[]> docBytes)
{
    Document original = new Document();

    using (MemoryStream resultStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        foreach (byte[] docByte in docBytes)
        {
            using (MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream(docByte))
            {
                Document doc = new Document(byteStream);
                original.Pages.Add(doc.Pages); //I basically want to add all pages from each doc into 1 doc.
                original.Save(resultStream); //this fails if docBytes is more than 1
            }
        }

        return resultStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[Error] Failed with exception.System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
```

How can I save these values in between creating new streams?

The [API documentation](https://apireference.aspose.com/pdf/net/aspose.pdf/document) of the Document class.

Comment: To know how it exactly fails, please post the code for Document. If you don't want it to fail, make a copy of what you have received in that class, instead of using the stream that has been passed.

Comment: @MartinVerjans The class doc can be found here: https://apireference.aspose.com/pdf/net/aspose.pdf/document

Comment: The memory is being consumed anyway - disposing a `MemoryStream` doesn't release it any faster. `MemoryStream` doesn't have any unmanaged resources in it. Adding them to a list may mean the reference is held longer, yes. Hence why I'd suggest starting with just removing the `Dispose`. Memory behaviour will be the same (since `MemoryStream.Dispose` does effectively nothing). Give it a try - does it work?

Comment: Yep, seems to work, thanks.